# Get an object_x with only the first record of the object_x Set with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm working on a `Java EE` application. In my objects structure I have the `Person` object which have a set of `Address` object. In one of my queries I'm supposed to retrieve a list of persons with only the first address of each person with `hibernate` query.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible in JPA, or ORM as a Person will have all his Address rows mapped to it. So you will have to do it manually, iterate over Person objects and get Address list and remove all elements except first.

Not a nice or efficient way though.

Comment: I can't do it manually because I have to add a sort to the initial query by an address attribute.